# Tomcat Login form not showing in Server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2, jdbcrealm

The problem is: when I click in a button, it is supposed that a "Tomcat Realm Security" Login form must appear because a protected resource is referenced, but not, is not happening. The "xxx" content of test.html page is shown.

Any help will be appreciated.

Probably is not important but: test machine is Windows with bitnami Tomcat LAMP, everything is working as expected. Target box is AWS Linux EC2 with Bitnami Tomcat LAMP preinstalled (the problem is here).

Directory where the web application is installed: ROOT (both machines)

index.html file contains the refrecence to the protected resource:

```
<li><a href="/test.html">Login</a></li>
```

The conf/server.xml is configured with the realm:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">  
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI  
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits  
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately  
         available for use by the Realm.  -->  
  <!--  
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"  
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>  
  -->  
                    <Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"  
                            driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
                            connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName"  
                                    connectionName="dbUser"  
                                    connectionPassword="pass"  
                                    userTable="users"  
                                    userNameCol="user_name"  
                                    userCredCol="user_pass"  
                                    userRoleTable="users_roles"  
                                    roleNameCol="role_name"  
                                    digest="MD5"  
                    />  
  </Realm>
```

In the table "users_roles" there is a user "test1" with assigned role "user"

The WEB-INF/web.xml file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5"xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">  
    <welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  

    <!-- ************************************************************** -->  
    <!-- **************** Roles Declaration *************************** -->  
    <!-- ************************************************************** -->  
    <security-role>  
            <role-name>user</role-name>  
    </security-role>  

    <security-constraint>  
            <web-resource-collection>  
                    <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>  
                    <url-pattern>/test.html</url-pattern>  
                    <http-method>GET</http-method>  
                    <http-method>POST</http-method>  
            </web-resource-collection>  
            <auth-constraint>  
                    <role-name>user</role-name>  
            </auth-constraint>  
            <user-data-constraint>  
                    <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->  
                    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>  
            </user-data-constraint>  
    </security-constraint>  
            <login-config>  
            <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>  
            <form-login-config>  
                    <form-login-page>/accounts/login.html</form-login-page>  
                    <form-error-page>/accounts/loginError.html</form-error-page>  
            </form-login-config>  
    </login-config>
```

Is there something missing here? Could it be because the Linux box have something else configured that is not there in Windows? (or is transparent for a user, as usual).

Thanks in advance 
Omar

Comment: It isn't going to fix the problem you are seeing but you should remove the HTTP methods from your <web-resource-collection /> otherwise your are *only* protecting those methods.